# Can't list files from directory

Tags: android, kotlin

I want list all files inside files folder. There are only 2 files, a .js and .json

[image]

This is my code but it isn't working, every time I click console prints `No files found or directory does not exist`. I don't know if file's folder must be on other location or the problem is the path. I'm following this [example](https://kotlinandroid.org/kotlin/kotlin-get-all-files-in-a-specific-directory/)

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContent {
         ReadFilesTheme {
            // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
            Surface(
               color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
            ) {
               Column {
                  ReadJSFilesButton()
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

@Composable
fun ReadJSFilesButton() {
   Button(
      onClick = { read() }
   ) {
      Text(text = "get files")
   }
}

fun read() {
   val directoryPath = "com/example/readfiles/files"
   val directory = File(directoryPath)
   val files = directory.listFiles()?.filter { it.isFile }
   files?.forEach { file ->
      println(file.name)
   } ?: println("No files found or directory does not exist.")
}
```

Comment: Those are files on your development machine. They are not files on the filesystem of the Android device.

Comment: `val directoryPath = "com/example/readfiles/files"` That might be a relative path on your PC but your Android app on your Android device and being not at home has no access to files on your PC. It's time you tell what you have in mind using those files for.

Comment: It's more curiosity about something else. For example, let's imagine that for X reason I have .js files that I need to cache and those files are in that folder. I would like to be able to list those files for caching. In that case, where should I put that folder so that it would be accessible on the device?

Comment: In assets directory. Just google for assets and you will know where to create that directory and how to use it. Read answer of Ariczek. But use only assets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally reached a solution. Maybe there is a simpler way but this is what has worked for me:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContent {
         MainActivityLayout()
      }
   }
}

@Composable
fun MainActivityLayout() {
   val context = LocalContext.current
   val assetManager = context.assets

   Column(
      modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
      horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
   ) {
      var fileList by remember { mutableStateOf(emptyList<String>()) }

      Button(
         onClick = {
            val files = assetManager.list("files")
            fileList = files?.toList() ?: emptyList()
         },
         modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
      ) {
         Text("List Files")
      }

      ShowFileList(fileList)
   }
}

@Composable
fun ShowFileList(fileList: List<String>) {
   Column {
      Text("Files in assets/files:")
      fileList.forEach {
         Text(it)
      }
   }
}
```

As has been said in comments and in last answer, I had to create the assets folder and put in there the folder containing the files I want to list.

Answer (score 2):

The files you are trying to read are inside your sourcecode **in your PC**. They are not present in the Android device, where you are executing your binary / compiled code.

See the following [for Android application resources overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources).

You can place your files (which you know at compile time) to the *assets* or to the *res/raw/* under resources.

You can get inputStreams for those files like follows:

```
context.assets.open("config_in_assets.json")
context.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.config_in_res_raw)
```

See the reference to file, assets uses exact file names, while resources has this `R.raw.` references.

Or you can download/create the files in runtime and placing them to the Android file system. See [View on-device files with Device Explorer](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer).

The path will start with `/` character as absolute path inside Android. See [Context.getFilesDir](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getFilesDir()) for a way of getting *suitable* path to place your application data on android file system.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. As blackaaps recommend, I'm going to use assets method. If I'm understanding your example, `context.assets.open("config_in_assets.json")`will let me read the file but that's not what I need. Maybe I'm wrong. What I need is list files from the folder, not read them.